# 2 arrays in a 1 function. Ordering array items by selected array in Smarty

Tags: php, smarty

**NEW QUESTION:**

I used this codes:

```
function FetchCategories(){
    // Get categories array
    $categories = $this->dbh->getAll("select id,category,categoryen from ".TABLE_PREFIX."categories order by category,categoryen", DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC);
    return $categories;
}
```

These codes order **categoryen** according to **category**. Second order array **categoryen** is not important. I want to order:

if **category** request, then order by **category**;

if **categoryen** request, then order by **categoryen**.

Is there any way to solve this?

---

**OLD, RESOLVED QUESTION:**

I have two category name phrases in the database. Their column titles are "category" and "categoryen". My php code like this:

```
{if LANGUAGE_ID eq "TR"}
                          <option value=\"{$categories[i].id}\">{$categories[i].category}</option>
{/if}
{if LANGUAGE_ID eq "EN"}
                          <option value=\"{$categories[i].id}\">{$categories[i].categoryen}</option>
{/if}
```

But I have old function which is support only category phrases

```
function FetchCategories(){         // Get categories array         $categories = $this->dbh->getAll("select id,category from ".TABLE_PREFIX."categories order by category", DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC);       return $categories;     }
```

How can I add "categoryen" support to the this FetchCategories function?

Comment: You surely can create multi-dimensional array with two results and return from that function.

Comment: Is this smarty template?

Comment: @Jack Yes, smarty template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer for changed question:

You can pass parameter to the function

```
function FetchCategories($currentLang){
   $order = 'category';
   if ($currentLang == 'en') {
      $order = 'categoryen';
   }

    // Get categories array
    $categories = $this->dbh->getAll("select id,category,categoryen from ".TABLE_PREFIX."categories order by {$order}", DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC);
    return $categories;
}
```

And then you need to run your function `fetchCategories($lang)` where $lang is your current language

or if you can use LANGUAGE_ID constant in your function you can do it that way:

```
function FetchCategories(){
   $order = 'category';
   if (LANGUAGE_ID == 'en') {
      $order = 'categoryen';
   }

    // Get categories array
    $categories = $this->dbh->getAll("select id,category,categoryen from ".TABLE_PREFIX."categories order by {$order}", DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC);
    return $categories;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this simple that way:

```
function FetchCategories(){
    // Get categories array
    $categories = $this->dbh->getAll("select id,categorytr,categoryen from ".TABLE_PREFIX."categories order by categorytr, categoryen", DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC);
    return $categories;
}
```

or as alternative:

```
function FetchCategories(){
    $lang = strtolower(LANGUAGE_ID)   
    // Get categories array
    $categories = $this->dbh->getAll("select id,category{$lang} from ".TABLE_PREFIX."categories order by category{$lang}", DB_FETCHMODE_ASSOC);
    return $categories;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Narcin, your codes works perfect!

Comment: But I couldn't use because there are new challenges for me like sorting names and too much looping for some codes. However, I will use in the future your codes. Best regards,

Comment: I found the reason of too much loop, it is my mistake. I understand the reason of wrong sorting/order: I used your first code. So, function sorts categories via categorytr, not second (categoryen). As much as I understand, using your second code is better for me but I couldn't. Because, actually my first category title is not categorytr, it is different. I writed it for easy understanding. So, I couldn't use {$lang} code. However, I understand lots of things. Thank you very much for your helps :)